# Biased Coin test

Tags: probability, statistics

A coin is equally likely to be either B(1/3) or B(2/3) [B(1/3) is Bernoulli distribution with p=1/3, and the same is for B(2/3)]. To figure out the bias, we toss the coin 99 times and declare B(1/3) if the number of heads is less than 49.5 and B(2/3) otherwise. Bound the error probability using the Chernoff bound.

My approach has been:

`mx = 99*0.33 = 33` &
`(1+d) = 49.4 / 33 = 1.5`, thus `d=0.5`

Then:

`P( X >= 49.5) <= e^((-1 * 0.5^2 * 33) / (2 + 0.5)) = 0.03688`

But apparently something is wrong…
Could you help?
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: At least you made some attempt to format the math.  Still, it is hard to read.  What Jose Carlos Santos commented: please use MathJax.